# ExtJS - showing a loading gif into grid cell on runtime

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2, extjs-mvc

I have a grid.Panel with some records, when a record is selected then a button in a ToolBar is enabled so I can start a "Long Running Process" on server side, so I need to show in cell (of that row) a Loading icon.

First I will show a **Messagebox** that will say "Initializing...", on that phase the server will log the task in a Queue so a Windows Service can catch that later. When the server returns a "success" then I hide the messagebox but now the Loading icon should be visible until the Long Running Process ends (maybe after 2 hours).

This button label is "Start Process".

On button click I have the following code:

```
onButtonClickProcess: function (button, e, options) {
        console.log('start process');
        Ext.MessageBox.show({
            title: 'Please wait',
            msg: '...',
            progressText: 'Initializing...',
            width: 300,
            progress: true,
            closable: false,
            wait: true,
            waitConfig: { interval: 200 }
        });
        var row = this.getGrid().getSelectionModel().getSelection()[0];
        Ext.Ajax.request({
            url: '/api/TimeSheet/QueueTask',
            method: 'GET',
            params : {
                "timesheetId" : row.get("TimesheetImportId")
            },
            success: function (response, opts)
            {
                Ext.MessageBox.hide();

                // TODO:
                // Here I have to show the loading icon into my row cell ??

            },
            failure: function (response, opts)
            {
                Ext.MessageBox.hide();
            }
        })
    },
```

Any clue on how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
var row = Ext.fly(grid.getView().getNode(rowIndex));
var cell = row.down('td:nth-child(' + colIndex + ') .x-grid-cell-inner');
cell.setHTML(value);
```

there is no framework function for that.